# eWam AppendObject fails to append object to the list

Tags: web-services, census, ewam

I'm running a census load through web services to create a member contract including voluntary spouse coverage. The employee and employee coverage are created succesfully, but when the spouse person object is being created, the correspondence fails to get appended to the correspondence list.

```
eWam 6.0.0.36  wInterface 4.1.24.0
```

Method: `CreateListOfActorCorrespondences`

```
forEach curActorCorrespondence in ListOfCreatedCorrespondences using rank
   **thisActor.Correspondences.AppendObject(curActorCorrespondence)**
   if rank = DefaultCorrespondenceRank
      curActorCorrespondence.SetAsDefault
   endIf
endFor
```

The same method is called to create the employee, but when creating the spouse the `curActorCorrespondence` which is successfully created isn't appended to `thisActor.Correspondences`. What could be causing the difference in behavior in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Look for errors

Start by searching the WSM error trace.
In this case the following error was found:

> 14/01/16 15:48:12            Process Id 4176 Thread Id 6440 Thread
>   Index 1   Minor error        WLISTOF.CPP
>   aListReftosType.ListInsert            is refused by the role:
>   aWFCorrespondenceVersionedByDate Add =0000:0000:2380:2F00 NSId = 0 Id
>   = 0 Version = 2147483647           Current Gold method:SLI_Actor._CreateListOfActorCorrespondences               #3

The issue is then clear, as `aXXX_CorrespondenceVersionedByDate` child class of `aWFCorrespondenceVersionedByDate` existed, but was not being created for the spouse. Further review of the class structure showed the class `aSPLI_CreateOrUpdatePerson_In` didn’t have any children classes so it couldn’t be a missing overriding/ child class causing the incorrect object to be created.

#### Make sure the XML nodes are representative of the class structure

Debug `fillvarfromparam` and `Deserialize` methods in classes generated by `wInterface` to finally find the issue with inconsistencies in the XML structure.

In this case:
Under employee tag:

```
<Correspondences xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Element xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:aXXX_Correspondance">
```

Under enrollment tag(where the failure was happening):

```
          <Correspondences xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:aXXX_Correspondance">
            <Element xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

#### Correct or Realign the XML

Moving the `xsi:type attribute` to the correct tag fixed the issue, allowing the correct correspondence list to be created and appended.